# backup script: delete old files not working

Tags: bash, cron, backup

I want to make a shell script which is run by a cron job to backup my websites + mysql databases + a delete script that deletes old backups (can of course also be put in one script).

I started slowly. I created the following 2 scripts:

**backup.sh:** works

```
#!/bin/bash
DAILY=`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`;
mysqldump --opt --user="XXX" --password="XXX" --all-databases > 
/var/www/XXX/backup/$DAILY.sql;
tar -czvf /var/www/XXX/backup/$DAILY.tar.gz /var/www/XXX/html/wordpress
```

**delete1.sh** works

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/www/XXX/backup/04-07-2018.tar.gz -delete;
```

The backup script is working. The delete script works like this as well, but this is not what I need. So I started modifying it:

**delete2.sh** does not work!

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/www/XXX/backup/*.tar.gz -delete;
```

So already changing only one parameter causes the script to not work.

**delete3.sh** does not work! This is where I want to go:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/www/XXX/backup/ -mtime +10 -type f -delete;
```

How can I get the delete script working? Thanks!

Comment: Why delete3.sh is not working? Can you show us the error message?

Comment: maybe try this: find /var/www/XXX/backup/ -name "*.tar.gz" -mtime +10 -exec rm -f {} \;

Comment: I am a completey noob to this. We do not have SSH acces to the server, only cornjob, so I can only test the scripts this way. Any way I can write the error into a log file?

Unfortunately your script is not working either.

Comment: One unsolicited advice, use `%Y-%m-%d` for your date formatting and meaningful sorting of the dailies becomes a breeze. As for saving output, you can add redirection `>& /tmp/my_output` if you have access to the machine to collect the file later. If you can SSH and switch to the user whose crontab this is suppose to be in, you could also just try running it from command line.

Comment: Thanks Ondrej I changed the variable. I get SSH access soon so I can test better.

Comment: For delete2.sh, you do not have to use find at all.  `$(rm -f /var/www/XXX/backup/*.tar.gz)` will do the same thing